# Slideshow is not seen in its entirety on the mobile screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, slideshow

as you can see in this photo: https://postimg.cc/YLC0cnsY the photo of the slideshow is not shown in full on the mobile screen. I wanted to see it in full, so that it would fit the screen, bootstrap if possible.In the computer it's shown right, but the problem it's in the movile screen. This is my css code and my html code:

```
.contenedor{

width:485px;
height:540px;
margin :auto;
}
 
 .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { 
    color:black !important;
}

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Slide</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js2/slick/slick.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js2/slick/slick-theme.css" charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css2/estilos.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/bootstrap.css" TYPE="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="slideshow2" >
            <div class="slide slide1">
            <a href="blog_principal.php"><img src="img2/1.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide1">
            <a href="blog_principal.php"><img src="img2/2.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide1">
            <a href="blog_principal.php"><img src="img2/3.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide1">
            <a href="blog_principal.php"><img src="img2/4.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide1">
            <a href="blog_principal.php"><img src="img2/5.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
            </div>
    </div>    
    </div>    
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js2/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(".slideshow2").slick({
            dots:true,
            arrows: true,
            fade:false,
            autoplay:true,
            centerMode: false, //centrar foto
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1


    });
    </script>  
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/utilidades.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How big is the photo and how much of it is missing? Are you sure this isn't what's causing the problem:`.contenedor{ width:485px;.. }`

Comment: the photo is 485x540. If i dont use .contenedor{width:485px:..} it is shown like this:https://postimg.cc/FkL79W46, the slide occupies the entire screen but the photo is shown on the left

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
HTML:
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <body>
      <div id="slideshow">
      <center>
  <img src="src of your first img" height="400px">
      </center>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
         
    

    

CSS:

    

 <style>
      #slideshow {
      border: solid 20px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: black;
      display: table;
      height: 40%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>


    

JavaScript:

    

 <script>
      let adding = 1;
      setInterval(function () {
      document.getElementById("simg").innerHTML =
      "<img src=\"p" + adding + ".jpg\" height=\"400px\"/>"
      adding++
      if (adding > 8) {
      adding = 1
      }
      }, 3000);
      </script>
```

name your imgs like p1.jpg,p2.jpg etc.
I named them like that.If you want yo can change,but also change
the 4rth line in script with your img name.

to make it fit to the screen on mobile use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer but i finally resolved it setting max-width and max-height instead of width and height:

```
.contenedor{
max-width: 485px;
max-height: 540px;
margin:auto;     
}
```

and removing class="img-fluid" from the images on the slide code.